# how to convert String into Date time format in JAVA?

Tags: java, datetime

How to convert a string in the form of `03/24/2013 21:54` into a Date object in java?

Comment: Take a look at [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Any Google search on terms "java convert string date" will bring up a plethora of SO posts on how to convert a String to Date, to Calendar, to DateTime, to Duration, to Period, to <insert whatever format here>.  Please search first before asking to prevent multiple efforts on questions that are already asked and answered multiple times.

Answer (score 33):

Using this,

```
        String s = "03/24/2013 21:54";
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
        try
        {
            Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(s);

            System.out.println("date : "+simpleDateFormat.format(date));
        }
        catch (ParseException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception "+ex);
        }
```

Comment: It is usually better to printout the exception, and it's message.  Otherwise you might be ignoring an important detail which would help you.  In this case I would expect an exception to be thrown and the format used might no be the default format.

Comment: following error occured :java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "03/24/2013 21:54"
 at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)
 at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:10)

Comment: can I get `year`, `monthOfYear` and `dateOfMonth` from parsed date? In my app I store date in form of `String` in database, and when I retrieve the date I convert back to `date`. Is it possible to get `year`, `month`, `date` from an **object of parsed Date**? Please reply.

Comment: Why not... you can get the values from the date object using Calendar

Comment: @Apurva Take a look http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_MONTH

Comment: @Apurva sample for Calendar http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-date-and-calendar-examples/

Answer (score 13):

With [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). And steps are -

1. Create your date pattern string
2. Create `SimpleDateFormat` Object
3. And parse with it.
4. It will return `Date` Object.

Comment: +1 for not giving the direct answer but making the OP go to the API to figure it out.