# Convert TextField into Date

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I want to convert TextField into Date.

```
private TextField fieldDateAgentAdded;
Date dateAgentAdded;


dateAgentAdded(fieldDateAgentAdded.toString())
```

Can you tell me how I can convert the String into Date?

Comment: Might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910344/how-to-convert-string-into-date-time-format-in-java

Comment: Yes I know about this but I need to shrink the example form the link and do the conversion in one line of code.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can do it in one line using:

```
dateAgentAdded(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(fieldDateAgentAdded.toString());
```

There is thousand of way to write date, so you don't really have choice, you need to specify the expected format.

Comment: I am not sure to understand, has mentioned, you need to tell SimpleDateFormat what the date looks like; does it starts with the day, then the month then the year - or is the the year at first, etc. It can't magically convert any date, imagine 02/03/04. (is it February third, or March second?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class.

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = DATE_FORMAT.parse("2013-12-4");

System.out.println(date.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the SimpleDateFormat class.  Here is an example:

```
String dateString = "May 14, 2012";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(dateString);
```

Now `date` should contain the date May 14, 2012. For more information see the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).