# How to get hours and minutes from a String variable ?

Tags: java, string, time

I have a `String timme = "13:10"`. I was wondering how would I best go about getting the hours and minutes and converting them into integers. i.e. int hours = 13 , int minute = 10. I know a for-loop wouldn't be the most efficient way, is there anything simpler?

Comment: From where do you getting this "timme" String from date Or Time Picker or something like that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910344/how-to-convert-string-into-date-time-format-in-java check this

Comment: if it is simply string then you can use string.split() method

Comment: Are you getting the time in a fixed format? then what about splitting the string.

Comment: I was getting the time from a timepicker, I have the solution now. Using the .split() method. Thank you all

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this way, by [split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method,

```
String timme = "13:10";
String[] time = timme.split ( ":" );
int hour = Integer.parseInt ( time[0].trim() );
int min = Integer.parseInt ( time[1].trim() );
```

Comment: @user2219097 , you can appreciate by accepting my answer :)

Comment: +1, same approach I was thinking. but why you have used **trim()**?

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj, It is security step to avoid any white space.

Comment: @user3317558: you are really doing well in SO. Happy to see your eagerness to answer in the very first day of joining.

Answer (score 11):

Better use `Date` and `DateFormat`:

```
String time = "13:10";

DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm"); // or "hh:mm" for 12 hour format
Date date = sdf.parse(time);

date.getHours(); // int
date.getMinutes(); // int
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this...

```
String time = "13:10";
SimpleDateFormat formatter =  = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
Date dTime = formatter.parse(time);
int hour = dTime.getHours();
int minute = dTime.getMinutes();
```

Comment: how about if time = "9:10" ? or time = "10:9" ?

Comment: what if the **time = "6:10"**?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Calendar` object of java instead of `Date` object,

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
        try {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.setTime(dateFormatter.parse("07:30"));
            String hour = String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
            String mintue = String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
            System.out.println("Hour: " + hour);
            System.out.println("Minute: " + mintue);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

**JAVA 8**

```
    LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse("13:10", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"));
    int hour = localTime.getHour();
    int minute = localTime.getMinute();
    System.out.println("Hours : "+hour +" Minutes : "+minute);
```